# CPT post count is 0 for the authors in the User list

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin

I have created few CPTs for my website. There are several guest writers for my blog. The posts that the authors write are CPTs. However, the post count beside the user list is still 0.

I want to display the actual number of CPTs associated with each author. Any solution to this?

Thanks in Advance.

The question is already asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278533/custom-post-type-author-not-associating-user-post-count-is-0-api-doesnt-ret), and the accepted answer still has the issue. I have added support for the author in my CPT.

Comment: Add a column to the Users list table calculating the count of CPTs each user have created. There is only regular post count is shown out of the box.

Comment: See answers to the [Showing User's Post Counts by Custom Post Type in the Admin's User List](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3233/11761)